# SQLDelight Relationships

Tags: android, kotlin, relationship, sqldelight

I want to model relationships with [SQLDelight](https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight/), especially a **one to many** relationship.

I have 2 tables: `recipe` and `ingredient`. For simplicity they look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE recipe (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE ingredient (
  recipe_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (recipe_id) REFERENCES recipe(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So I have a list of recipes and each recipe can contain 0-n ingredients.

I have 2 goals:

- Write a recipe with all its ingredients
- Read a recipe with all its ingredients

I'm pretty sure the first one can only be done manually, e.g. insert the recipe then manually insert the associating ingredients.

For the latter I try to join the tables with this statement:

```
selectWithIngredients:
SELECT *
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN ingredient ON recipe.id = ingredient.recipe_id
WHERE recipe.id=?;
```

For which SQLDelight generates me a 1:1 relationship file:

```
public data class SelectWithIngredients(
  public val id: Long,
  public val name: String,
  public val recipe_id: Long,
  public val name_: String,
)
```

Is there any nice way to retrieve the data (recipe + list of ingredients) with one generated function? Something similar to [Rooms](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships) `@Embedded` and `@Relation` annotations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQLDelight is not so exquisite. All it does is give you a data class for each row of a query, if you want to do more complicated logic like mapping one table to a list of some other table than you will need to do that yourself in kotlin.

E.g. having Recipe like this

```
data class Recipe(val name: String, val ingredients: List<String>)
```

You can do this with your select

```
val rows: List<SelectWithIngredients> 

rows.groupBy { it.name }
    .map { (recipe, selectRows) -> 
            Recipe(name, selectRows.map { it.name_ } 
    }
```

Comment: I approve ! Kotlin is very good with this.

Comment: If I understood correct, this would mean I have to do 2 queries? Of course Kotlin is good at this, but this would most likely mean a worse performance than one query.

Comment: No, you can still use your only [SELECT](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mg3P3WMNbPnLtTnr39BxNW/4) query. It will return you the list of rows that SQLDelight maps to List<SelectWithIngredients>. And you'll have a name of recipe in each row. So you'll just need to transform it to get `Recipe` or use as is.

Comment: Ah yes. That should be sufficient. Thanks!